# move a widget into another widget

Tags: qt, layout, tabwidget, floating

I'm working with a `TabWidget` that allow users to 'drag out' its tab to be a new top-level widget.(i.e. make the tab floatable)

When a tab is dragged, I get the *content* (i.e. the target widget, we call it `tar_widget`) and remove the original tab, then construct a new top-level widget, put the `tar_widget` into a new layout, and assign the layout to the new-created widget.

I want the `tar_widget` to be shown into the new-created widget **but** actually not.

I already did the homework that `QTabWidget` consists of a `QTabBar` and a `QStackedWidget`, I also tried that *reset the parent* of the `tar_widget` and *remove the layout* which it used to belong, however the problem still exists.

I hope someone would tell me if i did something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally noticed that the `tar_widget` was a QGLWidget, That was the problem.

I've learned that the QGLWidget would attach an openGL context, as I moved it into another widget, the context could not move to the new parent widget(on Windows), as the document said.

The solution is to use a dummy widget as the parent of `tar_widget` and move the dummy widget into another widget.